# Angular : Loading div not showing correctly on click of the checkbox event

Tags: angular

I am trying to show a loading div when the user clicks the checkbox in angular 7 application. I am trying to use a boolean flag called ShowLoader but if I set that to true in the event, the loading div does show and does not go away. If I set the flag to false , the loading div never shows. How do I control that behavior

Screenshot

[image: ec]

Html

```
<div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" checked="checked"
            (click)="isInvestedSelected($event)" />
        <label for="chkInvested">Invested</label>

    </div>


    <div class="card scrollClass">
        <div class="card-header panel-heading">
            <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Legal Fund Classes</span>
            <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
                <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; margin-left: 10px"
                    class="btn btn-default pull-right" (click)="openCloneModal()"> <i data-bind="visible: true"
                        class="fa fa-copy"></i> Clone</button>

                <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right"
                    (click)="openLegalFundClassModal()"> <i data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add Class</button>
             </div>
        </div>
         The value of showloader is  {{ShowLoader}}
        <div *ngIf="!LegalFundClasses || !LegalFundClasses.AllTerms || !LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassColumnNames || ShowLoader" style="padding-top:10px">
                <div class="alert alert-warning" style="text-align:center" role="alert">
                    Loading... Please Wait
                </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="LegalFundClasses && LegalFundClasses.AllTerms && LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassColumnNames">
            <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
                <tr *ngFor="let c of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassColumnNames">

                    <ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
               </tr>
        </div>     
    </div>
```

Component

```
public get ShowLoader(): boolean {
    return this._showLoader;
}

public set ShowLoader(value: boolean) {
    this._showLoader = value;

} 

 isInvestedSelected(s) {
        this.ShowLoader = true;
        this.LegalFundInvestedDetailsEvent.emit(s.target.checked);
        this.termsStateService.IsInvested = s.target.checked;

    }
```

Comment: I tried this     ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.ShowLoader = false;
    }  but  it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Try below changes in your component:

- Initialize ShowLoader with default boolean value as false
- Now toggle the ShowLoader value inside **isInvestedSelected** method

  ```
  ShowLoader: boolean = false;
  isInvestedSelected(s) {
  this.ShowLoader = !this.ShowLoader;
    ..........
    ..........
  }
  ```

Comment: Nope that wont work as it will set it to true or false until I click and the loader remains there. What  I am looking for is the loader should disappear once the content has been loaded. In this case if the showloader is set to true, the loader continues showing until I uncheck he checkbox

Comment: Then add showLoader in the method, which loads all the content. Is it residing in the same component?

Comment: I am in the child component and the load is triggered in the parent component